# Taking into account a predictor's accuracy when calculating probability.

Tags: probability, statistics

Lets assume that you are blind. And you are also given the task of sorting a line of randomly ordered humans into a group of males and females.

Let us also assume that the actual population proportion of males and females is the same, that is `50%` male and `50%` female.

You have a friend sitting beside you that is not blind, but has poor eyesight. Every time a person steps up before you, your friend gives you his best guess - but he **only gives you a guess when he is sure of himself** (thus his predictions are not for every human that steps up). Out of the guesses he does give, he is correct `75%` of the time.

---

> Question 1) A person walks up to you, and your friend **tells you he is male**. What is the probability that the person is male?
>
> Question 2) A person walks up to you, and your friend **tells you nothing**. What is the probability that the person is male?
>
> Question 3) Would any answer to the above 2 questions change if your friend gave an answer everytime instead of only sometimes? (he makes a prediction for **EVERY** human now - **instead of only when he is sure of himself**, unfortunately now his accuracy rate drops to `68%`)

---

My attempts:

Question 1) 75%

Question 2) 50%

Question 3) Yes.

The answer to `Question 1` would change to 68% and

The answer to `Question 2` would be N/A - since the question no longer makes sense (tells you nothing vs always tells you something)

Am I correct?

Comment: Question $3$ seems odd.  You are told that his predictions are correct $75\%$ of the time so, yes...that answer does not change.  But $2$ becomes unanswerable as the event it supposes can't occur.

Comment: @lulu, the question has since been changed

Comment: I think you are correct, but that on question 3) also answer "yes" will be okay. This because the situation sketched in question 2) will not occur (it cannot happen that your friend tells you nothing). Then any conclusion is vacuously true.

Comment: Still seems odd.  They tell you the new answer to $1$, and $2$ is still ill-defined.  I think your answers are perfectly good given the questions.

Comment: @lulu Further modifications have been made after looking at your comment along with (drhab's). Do you now think my answers are correct?

Comment: I don't understand your edit to your response.  Suppose I said "You roll two ordinary dice.  Given that the first one comes up $7$, what is the probability that the second comes up $1$?"  The condition, coming up $7$, is impossible, so the conditional probability is undefined.

Comment: @lulu What on earth are you on about? Has your concern of `question 2` being undefined not already been addressed by the 2nd last line?

Comment: I don't understand your line "tells you nothing vs always tells you something".    What does that add?  But, enough.  The question is very poorly worded...your answer is as good as one could reasonably ask.